# search two fields in two table mysql show in the one result

Tags: mysql

table1 - user

```
uid  (int)
user_name (varchar)
job  (int)  relation to table2 `job`.`job_id`
```

table2 job

```
job_id  (int)
job_name (varchar)
```

I want my user search the job_name or user_name can show in the one result

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | uid        | user_name   | job | object1 | object2 | sortID |
 +------------------------------------------------------------+
 | 12345     | Joe         | 1   |  222    |    444  |   66   |
 | 12346     | John        | 2   |  222    |    444  |   66   |
 | 12347     | David       | 30  |  333    |    444  |   66   |
 | 12355     | Peter       | 50  |  333    |    555  |   77   |
 +------------------------------------------------------------+


+-------------------------+
 | job_id  | job_name     |
 +------------------------+
 | 1      | teacher       |
 | 2      | doctor        |
 | 3      | driver        |
 | 50     | it support    |
 +------------------------+
```

I want to search doctor I can see John information

How to create my sql statement?

Comment: Write one query that searches for the username, another query that joins the tables and searches for the job name, then combine them with UNION.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I had tried many times. I think that's not work, so I don't send that code to here. I apologize

Comment: Of course your code doesn't work, that's why you're here. But you have to show your effort, so we can then show you where you went wrong, and you will learn from it. You don't learn anything by just copying from us.

Comment: Ok, I got your mean. Thanks so much Barmar. that's the last time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select u.user_name, j.job_name from user u left join job j on j.job_id = u.job_name where j.job like "%$key%";
```

That was what i understanded of your question :)

Comment: He said "search the job_name or user_name". This just searches the job name.

Comment: `j.job` should be `j.job_name`.

Comment: Why left join? This should be inner join.

Comment: @Barmar its my Default xD

Comment: thanks but, your sql just can search job_name...?

I just one input, if search "Peter" I need show Peter information, and if search "driver", I need show David  information

Comment: @Infem401CedupHH It's the wrong default. `LEFT JOIN` should only be used when you need to include results from the first table that don't have a match in the second table. `INNER JOIN` is more efficient, so it should be used when you only need matching rows.

Comment: Select u.user_name, j.job_name from user u left join job j on j.job_id = u.job_name where j.job_name LIKE "%$key%" or u.user_name LIKE "%$key%"  ;---- OK Now thanks